# Does iOS provide AirPlay-related HTML5 video events?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video, airplay

Is there an event that fires when AirPlay toggles between say an AppleTV to an iPad and vice versa?

Comment: sounds very interesting, show us what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks but doing nothing just yet, I just want to know when a user has selected an AirPlay option (ex: AppleTV or iPad). Is there an event that I can listen for via JS?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understand what you mean, you want to listen to the AirPlay "target device selection" event in your web app, e.g. when user performs selection like so:

[image: AirPlay]

Unfortunately, there isn't such an event even in the native objective-c [MPMoviePlayerController class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController) and neither in the client-side video control, see [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4_3.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. I guess we can all play the wait game until something like this becomes available.

Comment: Finally, (after 2yrs) we can do this using the iOS7 AirPlay API.